# How to speed up request 'SELECT'?

Tags: postgresql

I have a large table (90 GB) with data:

```
       col1     col2
----------------------
   1   str1     one
   2   str2     two
   3   str3     three
   4   str2     two
   5   str1     seven
   6   str4     seven
   7   str3     three
```

**col1** is *character varying* type, and **col2** is *varchar* type. The **col1_idx** index has been created on the **col1** column.

In order not to perform separately many queries like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col1='str1';
```

I making one query to find matches on the **col1** column like so:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col1 in ('str1', 'str4')
```

As a result of the request, I get:

```
['str1:one', 'str1:seven', 'str4:seven']
```

But both in the first and in the second cases, queries are executed very slowly (>20 min). Computer resources (processor, memory and hard disk) are hardly used.
Tell me **how to fix this query** or **tune the database to speed up** the search for matches on the **col1** column? I have PostgresQL 12 database installed.

**UPD1:**
Executed a small query (EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT) of 120,000 rows in small DB with size 2Gb (for example):

```
.....[]))">, <Record QUERY PLAN='Planning Time: 88.939 ms'>, <Record QUERY PLAN='Execution Time: 3026.371 ms'>]
```

Comment: Can you show the output from 'explain analyse select ...'? How many rows are there? If there are many rows with same value it may not resort to the index but rather a table scan instead.

Comment: @kometen I update question

Comment: @Владимир  Your edit doesn't include any of the valuable information of an EXPLAIN ANALYZE.  It looks like you replaced the useful parts with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) by including the other column(s) in the index. This way, there is no need for table lookup.

For example:

```
CREATE INDEX table_name ON table_name(col1) INCLUDE (col2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an index will increase performance if the col1 values are selective for "str1" and "str4"

Additionally, to reduce the table size, it is best practice to use the character length of the columns as small as possible